# What's the grammar meaning of '&buf_pool->watch[0]'?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I read code in `buf0buf.cc` of mysql's innodb buffer source code here:

[link from git hub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.cc)

And I got this:

`&buf_pool->watch[0]`

What is the value of the statement? address? or another value?

What does the code mean?(grammar meaning)

Comment: What do *you* think the expression does? Why do you think that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the meaning of the code in the grammar level is enough for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), this expression is parsed like:

```
&( (buf_pool->watch)[0] )
```

In English, the value is the address of the first element of the `watch` member container in `buf_pool`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `&( buf_pool->watch[0] )`? the parsing  `(buf_pool->watch)[0] ` will have the subscript to act on a `struct buf_pool_t*` type, while in `buf_pool->watch[0]` it should have effect on the type of `watch`.

Comment: `buf_pool->watch` will return a buffer. It is therefore OK to index into it post-return. This "translation" is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out.

First of all, let's take the `buf_bool` variable and look for its declaration. As you can see a few lines above, it's a function parameter:

> ```
> const buf_pool_t* buf_pool
> ```

This means we have to find the definition of the `buf_pool_t` type. With a mere full-text search, the type definition is not revealed. However, googling for "mysql buf_pool_t" gets us to http://www.iskm.org/mysql56/structbuf__pool__t.html, which in turn tells us that the type is defined in a file called `buf0buf.h`. That one's also included in the source file you've linked to:

> ```
> #include "buf0buf.h"
> ```

It does indeed contain the definition we are looking for, and that definition includes a member called `watch`:

> ```
> struct buf_pool_t{
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
>          buf_page_t*                     watch;
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> };
> ```

`watch` is a pointer to `buf_page_t`.

So if we go back to the statement in your question:

> ```
> &buf_pool->watch[0]
> ```

`watch` is interpreted as a pointer to the first element of a `buf_page_t` array, `watch[0]` is the first element itself, and the address-of operator yields a pointer to that first element.

So the whole statement reads as:

***a pointer to the first element of a `buf_page_t` array.***

Curiously, `&buf_pool->watch[0]` is equal to `buf_pool->watch`. Here is a simple (C++11) toy program to verify all of this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using buf_page_t = int;

struct buf_pool_t {
    buf_page_t* watch;
};

int main()
{
    const buf_pool_t example = { new buf_page_t[1] };
    const buf_pool_t* buf_pool = &example; 

    std::cout << typeid(&buf_pool->watch[0]).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(buf_pool->watch).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << (&buf_pool->watch[0] == buf_pool->watch) << "\n"; // prints 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&buf_pool->watch[0]` is the the address of the member 0 of `watch` contained in the struct `buf_bool`. Which is `watch` itself.
It is parsed like that because the whole `buf_pool->watch[0]` gets under the & (address of) sign.

You can check with this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct hello_t
{
    int before;
    int array[5];
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    struct hello_t hello;
    hello.array[0] = 100;
    struct hello_t* ptr_hello;
    ptr_hello = &hello;
    printf("ptr_hello = %X\n", ptr_hello);
    printf("&ptr_hello = %X\n", &ptr_hello);
    printf("&ptr_hello->before = %X\n", &ptr_hello->before);
    printf("&ptr_hello->array[0] = %X\n", &ptr_hello->array[0]);

    printf("");

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/fwDnoz